# Program giving out distance from a point

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates

I'm trying to make a program that after clicking a button gives you distance to a point. For now it should read your location and calculate the arc beetween points. I'm completely green at this, and don't know what doing wrong.

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetDistance);

function GetDistance(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  var x1, x2, y1, y2;
  x1 = crd.latitude;
  x2 = crd.longitude;
  y1 = 50; //The coords of the point are here, for testing I set it on N50 E 020
  y2 = 20;
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));

}

function GetOutput(GetDistance) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The distance is" + GetDistance();
}
```

```html
<p>Click to get your distance to the point</p>
<button onclick="GetOutput(GetDistance)">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: you don't call GetDistance with an argument and it requires a pos

Comment: It is not necessary to put `GetDistance` all over the place, and requesting the location is asychronous, so you don't return it from the function, you have to use a callback or async/await instead.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsbin.com/cifavifage/edit?html,js,output (note how and when functions are called, and what they're named (for readability purposes only))